# How to add customer address into bigcommerce store using API

Tags: api, bigcommerce

```
$createFields = array('first_name'=>$first_name,'last_name'=>$last_name,
'email'=>$email, 'company'=>$company,'phone'=>$phone,
'store_credit'=>$store_credit,'    
 registration_ip_address'=>registration_ip_address,
'customer_group_id'=>$customer_group_id,
'notes'=>$notes,'_authentication'=>$authentication);

print_r(Bigcommerce::createCustomer($createFields));'
```

I used `bigcommerce` function to create a new customer using API. The function is 
`bigcommerce :: createCustomer(vallues in fields)`.

I want to add address field for the customer. How to add it?